# how to disable autoconfiguration in integration test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying this:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
)

@EnableAutoConfiguration(
  exclude = [
    ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration::class,
    ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration::class,
  ]
)
@ActiveProfiles("testcontainers")
internal class RecordIntegrationTest {
  @Test
  fun contextLoads() {}
}
```

With `testcontainers` profile in application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: testcontainers
  r2dbc.url: r2dbc:tc:postgresql:///databasename?TC_IMAGE_TAG=13.2
  flyway:
    enabled: false
```

But then it tries to create repositories twice (and potentially other beans as well):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'recordRepository' defined in com.example.RecordRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableR2dbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in com.example.RecordRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableR2dbcRepositoriesConfiguration] for bean 'recordRepository': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in com.example.RecordRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.EnableR2dbcRepositoriesConfiguration] bound.
```

**UPDATE**

Found out that the test runs fine when I move it to the root package

```
src/test/kotlin/com/example/backend
```

But it fails when I put it in the package

```
`src/test/kotlin/com/example/backend/subfolder`
```

**UPDATE 2**

I figured out that if a repository defined under `src/main/kotlin` is in the same package as the integration test that exception shows up.

E.g.:

```kotlin
data class X(@Id id: Long? = null)
```

```kotlin
// src/main/kotlin/com/example/x/XRepository.kt
interface XRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<X, Long> {}
```

This test fails with the above exception:

```
// src/test/kotlin/com/example/x/XIntegrationTest.kt
@SpringBootTest(classes = [BackendApplication::class])
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
  exclude = [
    ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration::class,
    ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration::class,
  ]
)
@ActiveProfiles("testcontainers")
internal class XIntegrationTest {

  @Test
  fun contextLoads() {
  }
}
```

Deleting the repository or moving the integration test to a different package works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Include DataSourceAutoConfiguration in exclude block used by `EnableR2dbcRepositories` which disables the checking of datasource while starting up your integration test which is used by `Repositories` or you can configure the `datasource` to fix this issue.

The issue is basically due to the unavailability of datasource required by the repositories

Comment: adding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` to the excludes fails with the same exception, I think because it is from the jdbc package. But following your advice I found `R2dbcAutoConfiguration` which I can include to get rid of the exception, but now I get a missing bean exception regarding a repository..?

Comment: I think it might have to do with the `@ActiveProfile` - I added it to the question.

Comment: Since your repository requires datasource to function it needs an instance of datasource. you could configure the datasource on your .yml or .properties file

Comment: r2dbc is configured in `application.yml`

Comment: I found out that the test runs fine when not running from a subfolder/package. See update in question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your `src/main/java` you have a class that brings the annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. **This is the class that you want to exclude from your tests**, when you have defined your own `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in some other class in test package.

Comment: I do not use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` directly, but I think `@SpringBootApplication` brings it in. But this is not a configuration and cannot be excluded.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the `@ActiveProfile` - I added it to the question.

Comment: @Stuck it uses the `/com/example/backend/subfolder` to register components on main project for test. So when you move inside another package it does not register all those components in main project. Check your annotations on test folder. Post all of the classes here and we locate the error

Comment: I added the `classes` for the `SpringBootTest` explicitly and found out that the repository definition in the same package is a problem. I updated the question again with the details.

Comment: @Stuck have you also defined repository interfaces in your test package?

Comment: no, the only class in the test package is the `XIntegrationTest`